# What are the best practice to handle errors on NodeJS, and to work on validation within the model props using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, error-handling

BEST PRACTICE NODEJS :
As I am working on a back-end nodeJS application,
what are the best practice especially when it comes to validate your props,

like email, names ...etc

or this could be handled in the front-end part, it really confuses me.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your props/inputs either on the backend or frontend but it's important to do so on the backend and it's a good practice to do so on both ends.

Following are the ways of validating your props/input:

**Validation on the frontend (ReactJS code):**

```
const regex =
      /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (!regex.test(email)) {
      return alert('Enter email in correct format!');
    }

    if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !password || !passwordCheck) {
      return alert('Enter all fields!');
    }
```

**Validation on the backend (ExpressJS code):**

```
const { password, passwordCheck, firstName, email, lastName, employId } =
      req.body;

if (!password || !passwordCheck || !firstName || !email || !lastName)
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        message: "Enter all fields' values!",
      });

    if (password.length < 6) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        message: 'Password is too short!',
      });
    }
```

Hope the confusion goes away now.